Will the compiler know to skip this loop?
I am exploring the speed of C++ compared to other languages such as Python.  The following code counts to 100 million and prints out the final number (100 million).  I'm wondering if the compiler is able to tell that the variable n is used only to be printed, and so it can skip the loop entirely and just print out the final value.
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    size_t n = 0;
    while (n< 100'000'000) {
        n++;

    }
    
    std::cout << n << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

I thought that perhaps the answer lies in looking at the assembly code, but I'm not really sure how this works.

I my own benchmarks between C++ and Python using real world code, I have found that C++ is about x300 faster than Python.  Both the C++ and the Python were idiomatic code, without any extraordinary measures taken.  I have seen some Python benchmarks — with highly hand-tuned Python code (very non-idiomatic) and heavy reliance on NumPy — that the C++ code was only x2 faster.

Compiler explorer is really a nice tool to experiment with these kind of questions., and yes it will (with optimizations enabled -O3): https://godbolt.org/z/Wce8ExrjT (slightly simplified to return n instead of printing the output).

The compiler is allowed to do anything that will not change the observable behaviour (with a few exceptions, most notably copy elision can discard side efects of a copy). Will it do it? That's up to the compiler and compiler options used.

A fair number of compilers "optimise out" the loop, if compiling is done with suitable optimisation settings (like -O3 for g++, clang).  By default, modern C++ compilers are configured to NOT do optimisation though.


Will the compiler know to skip this loop?

Depends.
If you are compiling without optimizations enabled, the compiler does whatever you tell him to and does not optimize the loop away. If you compile with optimizations enabled, the compiler can recognize what you are doing and just skip the entire loop.
I have compiled your code with gcc at Compiler Explorer.

Without optimizations (-O0):
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], 0
        jmp     .L2
.L3:
        add     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], 1
.L2:
        cmp     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], 99999999
        jbe     .L3
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     rsi, rax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::cout
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(unsigned long)
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&))
        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        ret

The instructions from jmp .L2 up to jbe .L3 are the loop you programmed.

With optimizations (-Os):
main:
        push    rax
        mov     esi, 100000000
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::cout
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_insert<unsigned long>(unsigned long)
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rdx
        ret

The mov esi, 100000000 stores the value for n directly without going through the entire loop.

I have chosen the optimization level -Os here because it should generate the smallest executable, which means less assembly to look at (note that less assembly doesn't necessarily mean faster execution). However the compiler removes the loop already at the lowest optimization level (-O1).
For an overview about the gcc optimization levels you can take a look at this answer.

Thanks very much for this.  I was vaguely aware of optimisation levels before.  I read the answer you link to.  Why is it the case that lower levels of optimisation even exist?  For example, why would I ever want to use -O1 rather than -O3?

@gd1234 -O0 is needed for debugging so that the assembly actually represents what you wrote and you can watch what exactly your code is doing. -O3 is for fast execution of your program. -Os is to make your program smaller which could be useful on architectures with very limited storage capacity like microcontrollers.

@gd1234 Personally I have never wondered why there are -O1 and -O2 in between but I think it is primarily to allow the developer to choose between compilation time and execution time. Larger projects, especially if they are heavy templated, tend to take longer to compile. So if the execution speed is not too important you could choose a lower optimization level to fasten compiletimes. There might be other reasons as well.

@Joel - That's pretty close.    -On (n an integer) tends to increase both compilation time and program performance, as n increases.   -Os is typically like -O2, except that some optimisations that increase code (i.e. object/executable file) size are omitted.   -O3 tends to be aggressive with performance, but can [in some but not all circumstances] result in larger executables (larger short-running executables can sometimes give a run-time trade-off between loading an executable from disk and the increased performance once it is loaded).

"Learning by trying".
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    size_t n = 0;
    {
        boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer t;
        while (n<100000000UL)
        {
            n++;
        }
    }
    std::cout << n << std::endl;
}

Here's the non-optimized case:
stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ g++ Test.cpp -lboost_timer && ./a.out
 0.465022s wall, 0.460000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.460000s CPU (98.9%)
100000000

And this is with optimization:
stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ g++ -O2 Test.cpp -lboost_timer && ./a.out
 0.000008s wall, 0.000000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.000000s CPU (n/a%)
100000000

That's quite a massive difference for something that basically does nothing, so the only actual optimization to explain that would be the removal of the loop...
However, let's try something else: replace the one line with
volatile size_t n = 0;

Now, let's take a look:
stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ g++ Test.cpp -lboost_timer && ./a.out
 0.538811s wall, 0.520000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.520000s CPU (96.5%)
100000000
stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ g++ -O2 Test.cpp -lboost_timer && ./a.out
 0.558776s wall, 0.540000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.540000s CPU (96.6%)
100000000

This time around, we have no significant difference, because the compiler has to treat the volatile manipulations as "visible side effect", so it can't optimize them away...

Yes, it knows. Actually there is a smart optimization around this type of codes in C++ modern compilers such as gcc and clang.
Compiler will undrestand that it can compute the result in compilation phase and just put the result in the process.
You can search about something like this: SCEV final value replacement or tree optimization. and this question.
gcc has a specific option:

-ftree-scev-cprop
Perform final value replacement. If a variable is modified in a loop in such a way that its value when exiting the loop can be
determined using only its initial value and the number of loop
iterations, replace uses of the final value by such a computation,
provided it is sufficiently cheap. This reduces data dependencies and
may allow further simplifications. Enabled by default at -O1 and
higher.

